# How to convert S57 chart to PNG image using the ogr2ogr

Tags: python, image-conversion, ogr

I have a S57(.000) chart file, I want to convert it using ogr2ogr to a PNG file. Which command line should I use? If not possible to convert direct to PNG file, can I convert it to other format like ShapeFile the convert to PNG file?

By the way, I am using wxPython. Is that ok if I just import ogr library and read S57 chart as a bitmap? How can I do that?

Comment: Look into the full [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) library, OGR is a subset that deals with vector formats only.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the GDAL tool called gdal_rasterize: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html